# Automapper with Visual Studio 2008 and Windows 7

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, automapper, nuget

Can Automapper can be installed on Visual Studion 2008?

As per the [site](http://automapper.org/), automapper requires NuGet and NuGet works only with VS2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AutoMapper is just a set of libraries. It does not require any installation whatsoever. It is irrelevant which version of Visual Studio you are using. The only thing which could matter is which version of .NET Framework you are using.

Download the dlls [here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/zipball/master), unzip to a location on your drive and then add a reference to them in your project so you can start using them.

Happy Mapping!

Answer (score 0):

On the page you linked to in your question it says:

"Alternatively, the major releases can be found as zip files from the GitHub downloads page."